# Ext js 4.2, local datetime filter on grid

Tags: mysql, datetime, extjs, grid, filtering

I have problem with local filtering on grid, on 'datetime' column. When I choose some date from datetime picker, the result on the grid is always empty. I tried a lot of combinations but I did not find a solution.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this datetime filtering ...

My model field:

```
{
 name:'creation_ts', 
 type: 'datetime',
 dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
}
```

My column in grid and filter:

```
    {
       header: 'Created',
       dataIndex: 'creation_ts',
       renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       filter:
       {
          type:'datetime',
          date: 
          {
             format: 'Y-m-d'
          },
          time:
          {
             format: 'H:i:s',
             increment: 1
          },
          beforeText: '<',
          afterText: '>',
          onText: '='
       },
    }
```

creation_ts id MySQL 'datetime' field. It is displayed normally on grid, and I have problems with it only when I am using filter options. I also tried to configure grid datetime column to be shown as default filter datetime format 'm/d/Y H:i:s A', the result was the same.

Comment: there is no type like "datetime".change to only "date".

Comment: when i change to "date", grid wont display any reslut from server. php returns good result, but i can't display on grid. i tride changing all variables that point to date, but still dont have any result.

Comment: for display date in grid you have to use datecolumn.http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Date

Comment: ok, so i changed few lines like this:

Comment: model
        {name:'crts', type:'date'}
grid
        {
          text: 'created',
          dataIndex: 'crts',
          xtype:'datecolumn',
          format:'Y-m-d'
        }
and json data:
   crts: "2014/05/21"

I'm still having problems with displaying data on grid. 
Naresh, thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

```
model: {
    name:'crts', type:"date"
}
```

Column

```
column: {
    text: 'Created',
    dataIndex: 'crts',
    type: 'datecolumn',
    renderer: function(value, metadata,record) {
        return this.render_date(val);
    },
    filter: {
        type:'datetime',
        date: {
            format: 'Y/m/d'
        },
        time:{
            format: 'H:i'
        },
        beforeText: '<',
        afterText: >',
        onText: '='
    }
}
```

render function

```
this.render_date=function(val) {
    val = Ext.util.Format.date(val, 'Y/m/d H:i');
    return val;
};
```